# Give an example of a regulated function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm revising for an exam and was wondering if anyone could help with this practice question?

Give an example of a regulated function that has an infinite decreasing sequence $r_1>r_2>r_3>...$ in $[0,1]$ so that for each $n\in \mathbb N$, $f(x)<0$ for $x\in (r_{2n},r_{2n-1})$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (r_{2n+1},r_{2n})$.

I've come up with the following function: $$f(x)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       -1 & : x \in \Big(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}\Big)\\
        1 & : x \in \Big(\frac{1}{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n}\Big)
     \end{array}
   \right.$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

I'm fairly certain this satisfies most of the required conditions but I'm unsure if it is regulated. Would I be right in saying it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function is not defined on $\{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n \mid n \in \mathbf N\}$, but this can be fixed. Second, as $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ does not exists, $f$ is not regulated. You can change $f$ as follows, to ensure the existence of this limit: 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac 1{2n} & x \in \left(\frac 1{2n}, \frac 1{2n-1}\right]\\ \frac 1{2n+1} & x \in \left(\frac 1{2n+1}, \frac 1{2n}\right]\\
   0 & x = 0 \end{cases}
$$